# Chrome drawImage issue on recent Chrome version? Disabled accelerated 2D canvas

Tags: google-chrome, canvas, google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas, drawimage

Recently a Chrome extension our company uses was reported to be causing extreme slow down in the UI when in use. Ive been trying to find the cause of this issue.

After a week or two I have narrowed it down to the canvas's drawImage method.

Initial thought was that this method was holding onto the thread for too long.

This extension works great up to Chrome V43 (couldn't find chrome V44 anyway). With the current version 45, it causes heavy delay on UI response. Seems like a chrome bug.

Googling around I found this https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=490478

I am not sure if this is exactly the issue I am running into with drawImage but taking the suggestion from someone who posted there, I went into chrome://flags/ and disabled "Disable accelerated 2D canvas".

This instantly solved the issue & the extension is actually working better than ever before. The question is why? and how can this be used to make a temporary fix to the code since it'd be unreasonable to just ask everyone to disable this flag.

Comment: Test it on the bleeding edge [Chrome canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) build which you can install side-by-side. Maybe the issue is already fixed and in a few months the stable channel will have it fixed too.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I have tried on Canary and the beta versions of V46 & V47 but unfortunately no luck yet

Comment: This sounds like something we can't help with. You should get in contact with Chrome devs by submitting a bug report through https://crbug.com

Comment: Would forcing it for css work for canvas too, even with this flag set to true ?